# Calculate mean of specific rows Julia dataframe

Tags: dataframe, julia, rows

I am new to Julia and I have a relatively simple question (I think) about calculating means in Julia dataframes.

Imagine I have the following dataframe:

```
df = DataFrame(A=1:12, B=13:24)
```

Where my goal is to calculate the mean values in both column A and B for every 4 rows.

So in column A that includes 3 means for the values [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]. And for column B includes 3 means for the values [13,14,15,16],[17,18,19,20],[21,22,23,24].

I tried splitting the dataframe into 3 dataframes manually, but I have a large dataset so iterating over rows will be much more efficient.

Hopefully someone can help me out (I am using Julia version 1.0.3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the documentation here: https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/man/split_apply_combine/
So you could do

```
df.group = repeat(1:3, inner = 4)
aggregate(df, :group, mean)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that really helped me. I wasn't aware of using the aggregate function in this way, but thank you for the link to the documentation

Comment: That's great, glad to be of help :-) (oh, and if the answer was useful it's recommended to mark the answer as "accepted")